# File errors when I try to require a file in a different directory

Tags: lua, require

I'm having trouble with the lua require function. The file I'm trying to require is in

> ../node_modules/lua-hill/modules/globals.lua

The error I am getting is: `LuaError: Module 'globals' not found!`

My code:

`package.path = '../node_modules/lua-hill/modules/?.lua;' .. package.path
local test = require("globals")`

Comment: What version of Lua are you using?

Comment: I wrote a some code to try reproducing the problem you encountered. I tried setting `package.path` in the way you did, and I also reversed the two strings being concatenated. In both cases I was able to successfully load the desired module. Right now all I can say is verify that you have the right file path, or put in the exact path name instead of using `..`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the debug info like this:
`> tmp = require "tmp"
    stdin:1: module 'tmp' not found:
            no field package.preload['tmp']
            no file 'C:\lua\lua\tmp.lua'
            no file 'C:\lua\lua\tmp\init.lua'
            no file 'C:\lua\tmp.lua'
            no file 'C:\lua\tmp\init.lua'
            no file 'C:\lua\..\share\lua\5.3\tmp.lua'
            no file 'C:\lua\..\share\lua\5.3\tmp\init.lua'
            no file '.\tmp.lua'
            no file '.\tmp\init.lua'
            no file 'C:\lua\tmp.dll'
            no file 'C:\lua\..\lib\lua\5.3\tmp.dll'
            no file 'C:\lua\loadall.dll'
            no file '.\tmp.dll'
    stack traceback:
            [C]: in function 'require'
            stdin:1: in main chunk
            [C]: in ?`

So you can check your load path in this infomation.